# How to confiure chart's x axis labels?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, webix

I have a ui.chart with a big dataset where a needed value depends on a day of the month.

What I want to do is to configure xAxis to show the label only for the first day of the month. Something like

[image]

Is it possible to configure the chart such way? Here's a code of my configuration: http://webix.com/snippet/44abd3aa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xAxis:{
    template:function(date){
      if (date.date === '01') {
         return date.month;
      }

    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

@Denys has used date, but you can also perform the data object operations as :

```
xAxis:{
    template:function(obj){
      if (obj.date == '01') {
         return obj.month;
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I realize that it's a data item object